# JDA 5 SelectMenu create notwork?

Tags: discord-jda

When I use the code written in the wiki, an error occurs in create.

● https://jda.wiki/using-jda/interactions/#select-menus-dropdowns

I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [StringSelectMenu](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/components/selections/StringSelectMenu.html) and [StringSelectInteractionEvent](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/interaction/component/StringSelectInteractionEvent.html).